# Automatically remove white space in parenthesis and set number of digits in Word table

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm exporting tables from a statistics program but I am left with a table where there is white space inside the parenthesis.

I'd also like to set the number of digits after the decimal point. Is there a macro that would somehow allow this to be done instead of having to do it manually every time - which is very time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Try recording a macro of you replacing "( " with "(" and the same for the other bracket and run that when required.

Regarding the numbers of digits I would suggest setting the number of significant digits in the statistics program if possible as Word isn't really setup for those sorts of things.